# How to handle the generic type Object with protocol buffers, in the .proto file?

Tags: object, protocol-buffers, generic-list

I've spent some time looking for some alternative to handle generic objects, I've seen questions similar to mine, but not as specific I suppose?
Protocol buffers has multiple scalar types that I can use, however they are mostly primitive.
I want my message to be flexible and be able to have a field that is a List of some sort.

Let's say my .proto file looked like this:

```
   message SomeMessage
   {
      string datetime = 1;
      message inputData // This would be a list
      {
         repeated Object object = 1;
      }
      message Object 
      {
          ? // this need to be of a generic type - This is my question
          // My work around - Using extentions with some Object
          //List all primitive scalar types as optional and create an extension 100 to    max;
      }
      message someObject //some random entity - for example, employee/company etc.
      {  
          optional string name = 1; optional int32 id = 2;
      }
      extend Object 
      {
          optional someObject obj = 101;
      }
  }
```

And this would be fine, and would work, and I'd have a List where Objects could be of any primitive type or could be List < someObject >.
However- The problem here, is that any time I needed to handle a new type of object, I'd need to edit my .proto file, recompile for C# and java (The languages I need it for)...

If protocol buffers is not able to handle generic object types, is there another alternative that can?
Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The proto language supports neither generics nor inheritance. That is not supported AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you Marc! I will put this as an answer.

Comment: Check out this latest doc to know about supported datatypes :  https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As Marc Gravell stated above - Protocol Buffers do not handle generics or inheritance.

Answer (score 13):

Though I am late, just for the sake of new audience,
you can use bytes in place of object and that can be any object which you can serialize/de-serialize.

Comment: ok, we can map it like bytes, but how we can handle it on client side??

Comment: Client is the one storing it. You can have a fully qualified class name as one of the protobuf property

Answer (score 9):

Here is the [protobuf 3 definition of Struct](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/struct.proto) which basically uses `oneof` to define such "generic" message type.

Answer (score 8):

It IS possible to achieve generic message functionality but still adding new types will require rebuilding proto classes.

You use wrapper class

```
message Wrapper {
    extensions 1000 to max;
    required uint32 type = 1;
}
```

Then add some types

```
message Foo {
    extend Wrapper {
        optional Foo item = 1000;
    }

    optional int attr1_of_foo = 1;
    optional int attr2_of_foo = 2;
    optional int attr3_of_foo = 3;
}

message Bar {
    extend Wrapper {
        optional Bar item = 1001;
    }

    optional int attr1_of_bar = 1;
    optional int attr2_of_bar = 2;
    optional int attr3_of_bar = 3;
}
```

See how we extending Wrapper class in classes that we want to be stored by Wrapper class using extension.

Now, example of creating Foo wrapped object. I'm using Python, since it's most condensed form. Other languages can do the same.

```
wrapper = Wrapper()
wrapper.type = Foo.ITEM_FIELD_NUMBER
foo = wrapper.Extensions[Foo.item]
foo.attr1_of_foo = 1
foo.attr2_of_foo = 2
foo.attr3_of_foo = 3
data = wrapper.SerializeToString()
```

And example of deserializing

```
wrapper = Wrapper()
wrapper.ParseFromString(data)
if wrapper.type == Foo.ITEM_FIELD_NUMBER:
    foo = wrapper.Extensions[Foo.item]
elif wrapper.type == Bar.ITEM_FIELD_NUMBER:
    bar = wrapper.Extensions[Bar.item]
else:
    raise Exception('Unrecognized wrapped type: %s' % wrapper.type)
```

Now, because you want generic collection, make Wrapper a repeated field of other message and voilà.

Of course it's not complete solution, this architecture will need some more packaging to make it easy to use. For more information read about Protobuf extensions, especially nested ones (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#nested) or google about item marshalling.